# degrees, minutes, seconds OR degrees minutes seconds OR ...?

Tags: commas

I am revising my dissertation, and in my methods section I have the following sentence:
"I used an online converter [ref] to determine UTM coordinates from GPS coordinates given in degrees minutes seconds."

One of my committee members has suggested "degrees minutes seconds" should have commas between each word: "degrees, minutes, seconds"

She may also be suggesting to put "and" before "seconds," but I'm not sure if I'm reading the squiggle correctly.

I have not had any luck locating a rule for this, and have seen it both ways in different publications.

I also saw it written "degrees-minutes-seconds" in a response to a different question on here.

Does anybody know if one way is more correct than the other?

Thanks!
Liz

Comment: It's a simple list of nouns, and, in most writing styles, would be written "degrees, minutes, and seconds", though some argue that the comma before "and" should be omitted.

Comment: Since you just need to identify the notation system, why not just *DMS format*, explained on the first usage. You are already using GPS and UTM, so its seems natural enough to me.

Comment: Commas it is, thank you! Phil, I had previously fully spelled out GPS and UTM before using the abbreviation. But thank you for the reminder I can use DMS if I mention it again!

Comment: I agree...write it out as "degrees, minutes, and seconds", and you might want to include "(DMS format)" after "...seconds", since you have (and presumably have defined) the abbreviations GPS and UTM elsewhere.

Comment: I think the above advice about defining and naming the format is good. However if you didn’t go that route, *degrees-minutes-seconds* or *degrees/minutes/seconds* look clear to me, especially in a scientific or engineering document. Commas and *and* could infer that it can be converted completely into minutes or completely into seconds etc.?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to point this out and if it’s a measurement that’s no more “a simple list of nouns” than is “feet and inches” or “metres and kilometres”. Using
“degrees minutes seconds” is a problem only because such things are meant to be expressed purely in numbers, as for instance, as 23° 27′ 30″ E. In that form, where is there any need for “normal” English punctuation, please?

If you must drop the standard form then, for instance, “yards, feet and inches” would be preferred and “yards, feet, inches” understood.
Is it not then clear that depending on context, “degrees minutes seconds” might just be acceptable and “degrees, minutes, seconds” understood but  but “degrees, minutes and seconds” preferable?

Comment: Why the  "please"? It comes across as sarcastic. Is it meant to be?

Comment: Thanks Mari-Lou A, and "please" there was meant to have its standard form of Engish courtesy.